# Simple way to get first word of a string

Tags: php, optimization

How do i get first word of a string in var1 and rest in 2nd var.

My Requirement:

```
$strInput = "SSCL BAl 101";
$strFirst = ...;
$strRest = ...;
```

My Output:

```
strFirst = SSCL
strRest = BAL 101
```

My Current Solution:

```
list($strFirst,) = explode(" ", $strInput );
$strRest = trim(str_replace($strFirst, '', $strInput ));
```

Is there any other simple way too?

Comment: Your use of `str_replace` is not appropriate, as it's a global search through the string. Consider the input `"SSCL BAl SSCL 101"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$strInput = "SSCL BAl 101";
$strFirst = strtok($strInput, ' ');
$strRest = substr($strInput, strlen($strFirst));

var_dump($strFirst, $strRest);
```

#### Output

```
string(4) "SSCL"
string(8) " BAl 101"
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/l485LJpj).

Comment: I got this one more convinent

Comment: Very nice.  I was working on something using explode then trying to glue the other pieces together for my own project.  Much better than anything I had come up with.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know php too well, but looks like you could always call `strstr()` twice (if you're using php >= 5.3.0). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

```
$first = strstr($strInput, ' ', true);
$rest = strstr($strInput, ' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the limit for the explode():

```
 list($strFirst,$strRest) = explode(" ", trim($strInput), 2);
```

I don't know about optimization, but it is one line and rather readable.  You could do it with a regex if you like:

```
 list($strFirst,$strRest) = preg_split("/ /", trim($strInput), 2); // PHP >= 5.3 I believe
```

**EDIT**
Added the trim for leading whitespace fail!